# I cant get Image URL for JSON file

Tags: reactjs, json, imageurl

I have some images on my computer, I want them to use in JSON files Now I need the image URL. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "imgUrl":"./path.to.img"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use it on the web page, you'd better upload them on cloud or your own server.

You can use something like https://imgbb.com/

and then when you successfully uploaded an image, paste it to your JSON file

```
{
 "url" : "https://ibb.co/5cNJQfr"
}
```